# Android emulator shows error when 2 apps with the same activity name

Tags: android, android-activity, emulation

I have 2 projects in my Eclipse. Both of them have a activity called "MainActivity". The weird thing is, when I tried to launch the 2nd app, the emulator showed an error and pointed it to the 1st app. I can bypass this problem by changing the activity name to something different. Then everything will be fine.

I suppose this is only a emulator problem. I haven't tested it yet but I cannot image this happening on real devices, which will make Android totally unusable.

But still, I need to use the emulator and I'd like to keep the name MainActivity. Has anyone has the same experience before? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you also have the same package name?

Applications are distinguished by their package names so you should change those on per-project basis.

**Update:**

In manifest [`package` attribute](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html#package) is prepended to [`name` attribute](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#nm) of Activity. Combined they must be the same as your full qualified class name.

```
<manifest package="com.myapp">
    <activity android:name=".MyActivity"/>
</manifest>
```

Comment: No the package name is different. :(

Comment: Turned out you are correct --- not the package name of the app, but the package name in Manifest. It has to be something like android:name="com.example.appone.MainActivity" (package name + class name) or it will be a problem. I didn't know this, all of my apps use the Class name only. What a potential hazard!

Comment: In manifest, `manifest/package` is prepended to `activity/name` and must be the same as you class' package name.